# Pygame head-on collisions not detecting

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, collision

Im really new to Python and recently I've been working on creating a small, space invaders style game in pygame. I've almost reached the end however, I want to make it so if the enemy ships (block) collide with my ship (player), a collision is detected, removing my both ships and displaying a short "Game Over" message.

So far I have the code for detecting when a bullet and an enemy ship collides, I have rewritten this for if my ship and an enemy ship collides but this code only works if I fire no shots, I also have to be moving from side to side for the collision to be detected (head on collisions do nothing) once the collision is detected and both ships disappear I am still able to fire bullets from the position at which the collision was detected. I have no idea why this happens. If anyone could help me out Id definitely appreciate it.

Heres the code in question:

```
for i in range(15):
    block = Block(BLACK)
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(55) # change to 155 collisions fixed
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

for i in range(1):
    player = Player()
    player.rect.y = 480
    player_list.add(player)
    all_sprites_list.add(player)

...

    for player in player_list:

        player_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(block, player_list, True)

        for player in player_hit_list:
            gameover.play()
            player_list.remove(player)
            all_sprites_list.remove(player)
            block_list.remove(block)
            all_sprites_list.remove(block)

     for bullet in bullet_list:

        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)

        for block in block_hit_list:
            explosion.play()
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 10
```

---

### UPDATE

I have now managed to get the collision to detect properly, however I am still able to fire once the ships have disappeared (due to collision) is there any way I can hide the bullet once the collision has taken place?

Heres my updated code:

```
for i in range(15):
    block = Block(BLACK)
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(55) # change to 155 collisions fixed
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

for i in range(1):
    player = Player()
    player.rect.y = 480
    player_list.add(player)
    all_sprites_list.add(player)

...

    for player in player_list:

        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, True)

        for block in block_hit_list:
            gameover.play()
            player_list.remove(player)
            all_sprites_list.remove(player)
            block_list.remove(block)
            all_sprites_list.remove(block)

     for bullet in bullet_list:

        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)

        for block in block_hit_list:
            explosion.play()
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with groups, you might want to use this function, for handling collisions between groups:

Would be something like this (I haven't tried your code)

`pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullet_list, block_up_list, True, True, collided = None)`

With both arguments True you remove both from the list. When you learn how to use groupcollide, you are going to notice that it's very useful.

Anyways, look for the function description in the pygame documentation and see some examples.
Hope that helps ;)